# Angular - issue with ng-Click and submit

Tags: angularjs, forms

Needed some help with AngularJS as I'm new to it.

I have a form which has a button to display a dialog box, and then once that dialog box pops up, user must submit the form from the button on the Dialog box.

But currently if the user hits enter in a textBox before the dialog box has been opened, the form gets submitted without the dialog generating.

The button on the main form looks like this :

```
<button type="button" class="xyz xyz-one" ng-Click="popDialog()">
```

And the button on the dialog which finally submits the form looks like this :

```
<button type="submit" class="xyz xyz-one">
```

Is there any way that on the UI when the user hits enter, the form is blocked from automatic submission and only the dialog pops up?

Comment: you can use ng-disabled to disable to submit button so the enter action or clicking the button can't submit the form until after the dialog has closed (and some property is set that the ng-disabled is bound to)

Answer (score 0):

On each of the textfields in your form, add this directive:

`ng-keydown="preventFormSubmission($event)"`

Then in your controller do the following:

```
$scope.preventFormSubmission = (event) => {
    // Keycode 13 is the enter button
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        event.preventDefault()
    }
}
```

`$event` is the object which holds all the data about the event that just happened (the key being pressed).
Calling `event.preventDefault()` will stop the form from automatically being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Change the button in the main form to

```
<button type="button" ng-click="submit()">
```